# System.FormatException:Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, file, math

**Problem:**

I was trying to make a simple notepad calculator, but it will stop at the 24th line and show me this error.

**What I tried:**

I tried to use the `TryParse` but it didn't work for me, but maybe I'm just too inexperienced in coding to use it properly.

**The original code(without `TryParse`):**

```cs
private static string Reader(string path)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    return str;
}

private static int Calculate(string st)
{
    string[] stNum = st.Split(',');
    int sum = int.Parse(stNum[0]); //code that causes problems
    for(int i=1; i<=stNum.Length-1; i++)
    {
        sum = +int.Parse(stNum[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] data = Reader("input.txt").Split('\r');
    MessageBox.Show("There are" + data[0] + "questions in total");

    int[] ans = new int[int.Parse(data[0])];
    for(int n=0; n<= int.Parse(data[0])-1; n++)
    {
        ans[n] = Calculate(data[n+1]);
        MessageBox.Show("The answer for the"+(n+1) +"question is" + ans[n]);
    }

    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo("output.txt");
    StreamWriter sw =fInfo.CreateText();
    foreach(int a in ans) 
    {
        sw.WriteLine(a);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

**The input notepad:**

[image]

Comment: 5.5 and -2.2 are not `int`

Comment: May I ask what should I do if I want to calculate them then? Use Decimal or Double?

Comment: Use decimal instead of int

Comment: _sum = +int.Parse(stNum[i]);_ will not sum anything

Comment: @inca2005 `decimal.TryParse`

Comment: Unrelated: use `using` or close the streamreader in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use decimal instead of int:

```
private static decimal Calculate(string st)
{
    string[] stNum = st.Split(',');
    decimal sum = 0;
    foreach (var num in stNum)
    {
        sum += decimal.Parse(num);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

with link it would look shorter and simpler:

```
private static decimal Calculate(string st)
{
    string[] stNum = st.Split(',');
    return stNum.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x));
}
```

Comment: Thank you,your answer give me a lot of help